# Payara/GlashFish won't start in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, macos-sierra, payara

I'm running Mac OS. I've set up the Payara server with NetBeans. And when I'll try to run the server it never shows the green 'dot' that indicates its online status, instead it shows the 'loading' dot forever.

However, I can access it on http://localhost:4848, but when I try to deploy an application to the server I get this error:

```
GlassFish Server is running.
Starting GlassFish Server
Initial deploying slit-ee to /Users/christian/slit/slit-ee/dist/gfdeploy/slit-ee
Completed initial distribution of slit-ee
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
/Users/christian/slit/slit-ee/nbproject/build-impl.xml:307: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 22 seconds)
```

And the full server log

```
objc[1865]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x105e334c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x105efb4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
nov 28, 2016 2:14:21 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@18808234 in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/Users/christian/opt/payara41/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/Users/christian/opt/payara41/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/Users/christian/opt/payara41/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/Users/christian/opt/payara41/glassfish/domains/payaradomain/config/logging.properties
Info:   Running Payara Version: Payara Server  4.1.1.164 #badassfish (build 28)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Registered fish.payara.ha.hazelcast.store.HazelcastBackingStoreFactoryProxy for persistence-type = hazelcast in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Info:   Registered Hazelcast BackingStoreFactory with persistence-type = hazelcast
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.28 started in: 47ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.28 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.28 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.28 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   Payara Server  4.1.1.164 #badassfish (28) startup time : Felix (33 542ms), startup services(5 715ms), total(39 257ms)
Info:   Payara Notification Service Started with configuration: NotificationExecutionOptions{enabled=true, notifierConfigurationExecutionOptionsList={LOG=NotifierConfigurationExecutionOptions{notifierType=LOG, enabled=true}}}
Info:   Cleaning JarFileFactory Cache to prevent jar FD leaks
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.28 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@7bca6fac as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@129fed45.
Info:   /Users/christian/opt/payara41/glassfish/domains/payaradomain/autodeploy/bundles does not exist, please create it.
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://192.168.0.183:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.0.183:8686/jmxrmi
```

Is there any security mechanism that prevents this on Mac OS?

Comment: I think this might be an error in NetBeans configuration. I can see from your log that you're using the `payaradomain`. Can you make sure that Payara is configured to start that domain in Netbeans too? There's no log message to say that Payara has received the file to deploy, it's just standard startup messages.

Comment: I've tested both.. both give same results..

Comment: Check around line 307 in your `build-impl.xml` file, that's where it's failing in NetBeans

Comment: Can't find anything that could be wrong there.. I think the main problem is that none of the servers boots up correctly.. I know that the project know about the server, since it will try to boot up the server, if the server is not already on.. Thanks for helping me, I think this is a very odd problem

Comment: The log file you posted shows a correct boot sequence and the fact that you can access the admin console seems to suggest everything is OK. What is around line 307?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Netbeans cannot connect to the started Payara Server. Maybe your issue is similar to this one with Netbeans and Tomcat on a Mac after some system update: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7680039?start=0&tstart=0

Here is a quote from that page:

> Step 1:  Go to system preference >Network>Select your wifi
>   connection>Advanced>select proxies tab.
>
> There check 3 options 1) Auto proxy Discovery 2)Automatic Proxy
>   configuration 3) web proxy(http)
>
> Step 2: Go to Netbeans>preferences>General> select use system proxy>
>   reload> test connection

Comment: WOW, I did try this before and it didn't work. I decided to give it one more try and I suddenly worked. Woah, hero of the day!

Comment: Thanks. And I even don't have a Mac myself :) The real hero is the one who posted the answer on apple.com...

Answer (score 3):

I found an alternative solution for me:
Go to Netbeans-> Preference-> chose No Proxy. 
Test the connection. should success, Press Ok. Then clean and run the application.

No need to change any network configuration on mac.

Comment: Thanks for another answer on this problem. I will not try it though.. Since I've got it working for now :-)

Comment: This is way more convenient than having to change network setting :-)