# Netbeans is not able to deploy web application on Glassfish in Mac os Sierra

Tags: macos, netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-4

I am trying to deploy a web application from netbeans to the bundled glassfish server. but its not deploying and running. get stuck for long time(5 or 6 min) and says can't start glassfish server, check user name and password or server log for other reason. user name and password all default. haven't touch it. But if i go to the bundle folder and run glassfish as asadmin, i can start and stop the server. seems like netbeans can't control it any more.

[image: Screen shot of the error]

[image: Glassfish Properties]

> Glassfish Log

```css
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Nov 30, 2016 10:24:34 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Nov 30, 2016 10:24:34 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Nov 30, 2016 10:24:34 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Nov 30, 2016 10:24:36 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@6cbfad8c in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 56ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (35,490ms), startup services(1,849ms), total(37,339ms)
Info:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@568750b7 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@78d71df1.
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://192.168.1.101:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.1.101:8686/jmxrmi
Info:   Domain Pinged: release.glassfish.org
```

I have tried to installed different version of Glassfish and netbeans. but same problem.I am guessing some sort of OS level configuration doing this. Removed java, netbeans and tried again.Nothing is working.

Even though Netbeans says can't start the server, eventually server get started and i can go localhost:4848. but the server is not sync with netbeans service tab glassfish(always frozen after startup).
[image: Glassfish admin page]

Comment: [This is a duplicate and the answer is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40846115/212224). It seems to be a problem with macOS, both GlassFish and Netbeans are working fine.

Comment: thanks mike. saved my day.

Comment: I find a alternative solution for me:

Comment: I found an alternative solution for me:  
Go to Netbeans-> Preference-> chose No Proxy. 
Test the connection. should success, Press Ok. then clean and run the application.