# Payara Glassfish 4.1.1 will not start in Netbeans 8.2 MacOSX

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, netbeans-8, java-ee-7, payara

Glassfish freezes at:

```
Information:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://192.168.0.119:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.0.119:8686/jmxrmi
```

I have tried to reinstall netbeans, reinstall glashfish, others projects also not working.

I get sometimes an error message:

```
Please check server admin user name and password properties.

Also please check the server log file for other possible causes.
```

And i think there is no new server.log file created but the file contains:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.0.117; nested exception is: 
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.0.117; nested exception is: 
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException [Root exception is java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: eleonores-air; nested exception is: 
Caused by: java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: eleonores-air; nested exception is: 
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: eleonores-air
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835870/payara-glashfish-wont-start-on-brand-new-mac-in-netbeans/40846115#40846115

Comment: Check the real `server.log` file on the system, not what is displayed in Netbeans. You should find it in GlassFish/Payara installation in `domains/domain1/logs`. If there are no errors, I guess that the server is running - check the answer in the above link.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The answer in the link above worked very well.